# Python-Beautiful Soup not parsing entire unordered list

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to scrape a website and having one part that is just baffling me.  There is an unordered list of locations served by organizations and I can seem to parse the entire list.

Here is an example of what the HTML looks like:

```
<div id="current_tab">

                <p class="view_label_type_geoserved" id="view_label_field_geoserved">Geographies Served</p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="view_type_geoserved" id="view_field_geoserved">
                        <p style="font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC; font-size: .9em;">North Carolina (NC)<span style="float: right; font-size: 0.8em;">North Carolina (NC)</span></p>
                        <p style="margin: 5px 0 3px 8px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #DDD; font-size:1em">Durham (serves entire county)<span style="float: right; font-size: 0.8em;">Durham</span></p>
                    </li>
                        <p style="margin: 5px 0 3px 8px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #DDD; font-size:1em">Franklin (serves entire county)<span style="float: right; font-size: 0.8em;">Franklin</span></p>
                    </li>
                        <p style="margin: 5px 0 3px 8px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #DDD; font-size:1em">Granville (serves entire county)<span style="float: right; font-size: 0.8em;">Granville</span>
                        </p>
                    </li>
                        <p style="margin: 5px 0 3px 8px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #DDD; font-size:1em">Orange (serves entire county)<span style="float: right; font-size: 0.8em;">Orange</span></p>
                    </li>
                        <p style="margin: 5px 0 3px 8px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #DDD; font-size:1em">Person (serves entire county)<span style="float: right; font-size: 0.8em;">Person</span></p>
                    </li>
                        <p style="margin: 5px 0 3px 8px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #DDD; font-size:1em">Vance (serves entire county)<span style="float: right; font-size: 0.8em;">Vance</span></p>
                    </li>
                        <p style="margin: 5px 0 3px 8px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #DDD; font-size:1em">Wake (serves entire county)<span style="float: right; font-size: 0.8em;">Wake</span></p>
                    </li>
                    <p style="margin: 5px 0 3px 8px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #DDD; font-size:1em">Warren (serves entire county)<span style="float: right; font-size: 0.8em;">Warren</span></p>
                    </li>
            </ul>            
</div>
```

and here is what I'm using to parse out the elements

```
for i in soup.find('div', {'id':'current_tab'}).findAll('p'):
    print i
```

and here is the results I'm getting, note it's only the beginning of the list:

```
<p class="view_label_type_geoserved" id="view_label_field_geoserved">Geographies Served</p>
<p style="font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC; font-size: .9em;">North Carolina (NC)<span style="float: right; font-size: 0.8em;">North Carolina (NC)</span></p>
<p style="margin: 5px 0 3px 8px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #DDD; font-size:1em">Durham (serves entire county)<span style="float: right; font-size: 0.8em;">Durham</span></p>
<p style="margin: 5px 0 3px 8px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #DDD; font-size:1em">Franklin (serves entire county)<span style="float: right; font-size: 0.8em;">Franklin</span></p>
```

Once I get the HTML back I have functions that will strip the text using regex and then join them into a single string, but suggestions there would be appreciated too.

Comment: Did you omit some <li> tags in that html example?

Comment: No, that is the code cut and pasted from the site.  I did add the formatting though.

Comment: Well then, I'm just working on suspicion here but maybe it's having trouble because of the excess closing tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the HTML you are dealing with needs a lenient parser to be parsed with.

Use either `lxml`, or `html5lib`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')  # or BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
for p in soup.select('div#current_tab p'):
    print p.text
```

Works for me, it prints:

```
Geographies Served
North Carolina (NC)North Carolina (NC)
Durham (serves entire county)Durham
Franklin (serves entire county)Franklin
Granville (serves entire county)Granville

Orange (serves entire county)Orange
Person (serves entire county)Person
Vance (serves entire county)Vance
Wake (serves entire county)Wake
Warren (serves entire county)Warren
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am just starting out with beautiful soup and still catching on to all the ins and outs.